# How to make Nautilus icons in Gnome 3.16 less fat?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, files, icons, ubuntu-gnome

Since I upgraded from Gnome 3.14 to Gnome 3.16, I have noticed that my icons in Nautilus have started eating a lot more than they used to, and have got really fat, is there any way now to decrease their size (maybe by altering their diet)?

This is what I mean, they are just too big, how do I shrink these fatties back to normal size?:

[image]

---

**OS Information:**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid
```

Comment: in Ubuntu 16.04 there is no such option as the ui was...heavy simplified Nautilus 3.16/3.18 support only "small" value for leftmost position of zoom slider and the small means 48x48px Hope it will be fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try putting them on a diet, however this may work better than that: **;-)**

1. **Open the <kbd>Preferences</kbd> menu via the <kbd>Files</kbd> menu**

   [image]
2. **Set the <kbd>Default zoom level</kbd> to <kbd>Small</kbd>**

   [image]
3. **Close the Nautilus Window and open another one**

   *Default*

   [image]

   *Small*

   [image]

Comment: :D  Good one! +1